# Alternativa para "no dominante" al hablar de las manos

Tags: vocabulario, antónimos

Mi esposa está escribiendo un instructivo y me pidió ayuda con algún antónimo para el concepto de "mano dominante".

Lo que no quiere es repetir tantas veces la misma palabra, porque finalmente el texto resulta un poco pesado, por ejemplo:

> Debe hacer primero el ejercicio con la mano **dominante** y luego con la **no dominante**.

¿Hay alguna otra forma de referirse a la mano que es menos hábil o menos preferida?

Comment: con menos destreza

Comment: Se me ocurre _secundario_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si bien una de las acepciones de "diestra" es "derecha", otras de sus acepciones es "hábil". Por lo tanto, podríamos hablar de "mano más diestra" y de "mano menos diestra".

En Internet encontramos muchos ejemplos. Solo menciono tres, para no aburrir:

> “(….) Siza se puso a dibujar su primer boceto con la mano izquierda y, aunque comentaba que se sentía torpe e impreciso, lo cierto es que el resultado final de aquel retrato realizado con su **mano menos diestra**, era, una vez más, un gran dibujo; quizás un retrato menos preciso que otras veces pero igualmente sintético y armónicamente fluido –como en los bocetos realizados con su **mano más diestra**-, porque en el acto del dibujo la habilidad manual y hasta la participación del cuerpo, seguramente son importantes, pero es al final el cerebro quien conduce. Aquella torpeza física que Siza confesaba, realmente quedaba relegada por su capacidad de síntesis y por el orden que componía todo el conjunto.” ([Fuente](https://stepienybarno.es/blog/2015/12/04/resena-del-libro-sizaxsiza-editado-por-fundacion-arquia-arquiaxsiza/))

> Una vez que te pones en posición con tu **mano menos diestra**, se sugiere que sujetes la mascarilla y con tu **mano más diestra** puedes dar las ventilaciones. (Fuente:
> ¿Cómo enseñar un procedimiento psicomotriz en la clínica ...https://es.coursera.org › lecture › residente)

> 6. Ponga la cabeza del recién nacido apoyado en la parte fija del podómetro o
>    cartabón y afirme el cuello con su **mano más diestra**.
> 7. Estire la rodilla del recién nacido con su **mano menos diestra**. (Fuente: https://xdoc.mx/preview/atencion-inmediata-del-recien-nacido-5feeaeb35c9b9)

Answer (score 2):

No creo sea necesario un antónimo habiendo definido una de ellas, lo más inmediato y comprensible es referirse a "la otra":

> Debe hacer primero el ejercicio con la mano dominante y luego con la **otra**.

> Debe hacer primero el ejercicio con la mano dominante y luego con la **contraria**.

> Debe hacer primero el ejercicio con la mano dominante y luego con la **opuesta**.

De cualquier modo, el antónimo de dominante es **subordinado**

> Debe hacer primero el ejercicio con la mano dominante y luego con la **subordinada**.

Comment: De acuerdo con otra/contraria/opuesta, pero creo que "subordinado" en este caso no corresponde, porque la derecha no "domina" a la izquierda (o viceversa)

Comment: Una mano no domina a la otra en una situación normal, pero en la destreza de un ejercicio, tal el caso planteado en la pregunta, si una mano es dominante, la otra queda relegada. Es la mano subordinada a la ejecución de la acción por parte de la dominante.

Answer (score 1):

Puede decir "utilice la mano de mayor habilidad" o "mano principal para usted".

*En el ejercicio debe utilizar primero la mano que tenga mayor habilidad y seguidamente utilizaremos la otra*.

- / cambiamos a la otra / a la mano contraria
- / continuamos con la otra / continuamos con la mano contraria
- / seguimos con la otra / mano contraría
- / pasamos a la otra mano.